# The second description of the x-axis in ggplot2?

Tags: ggplot2

I am wondering if there is a way to add the second description of x-axis in ggplot2 as follows: Here "the second description" refers "Sample A / Sample B / two arrows" colored in red (shown in the figure).

[Please click for the figure!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rICY.png)

Of course, I can just put the "second description" using PowerPoint as I did, but I just wonder if it is possible to add it using ggplot2.

Here is the code for the background plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)

x <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(100, mean = -2, sd = 0.022),
                v2=rnorm(100, mean = -1, sd = 0.022),
                v3=rnorm(100, mean =  0, sd = 0.022),
                v4=rnorm(100, mean =  1, sd = 0.022),
                v5=rnorm(100, mean =  2, sd = 0.022),
                v6=rnorm(100, mean =  3, sd = 0.022),
                v7=rnorm(100, mean =  4, sd = 0.022))
colnames(x) <- c("A",
                 "B",
                 "C",
                 "D",
                 "E",
                 "F",
                 "G")
head(x)

# Manipulate the data
library(reshape2)
data <- melt(x)
head(data)

# Generating plot
colors <- rainbow(7)

ggplot(data, aes(x = value, y = variable)) +
  geom_density_ridges(aes(fill = variable), alpha=0.6, bandwidth=0.1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors)+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 10),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 17, face = "bold", 
                                  margin = margin(b=10), hjust = 0.5),
        panel.spacing = unit(0.1, "lines"),
        legend.position="none") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype="dotted") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 2, linetype="dotted", 
             color = "red", size=1.2) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Groups") + 
  labs(title = 'Density plot of each group')
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you mean, but you can add text on the x-axis using the following in labs:

```
labs(x="←  Sample A        Sample B →")
```

I got the arrows from unicode here: http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_arrows.html

There are bigger arrows in the link if needed.

EDIT:

Here's your code adapted with the new labels in red font:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = value, y = variable)) +
  geom_density_ridges(aes(fill = variable), alpha=0.6, bandwidth=0.1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors)+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 12),
  axis.text = element_text(size = 10),
  legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
  plot.title = element_text(size = 17, face = "bold", 
                                  margin = margin(b=10), hjust = 0.5),
        panel.spacing = unit(0.1, "lines"),
        legend.position="none") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype="dotted") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 2, linetype="dotted", 
             color = "red", size=1.2) +
  xlab("   Sample A        Sample B ") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=40,colour = "red")) +
  ylab("Groups") + 
  labs(title = 'Density plot of each group')
```

[image]

You can also push the labels further apart by adding extra spaces. Bring them closer together with fewer spaces.

Comment: Thank you so much! I know, my question was a bit misleading, but this is exactly what I wanted! I guess this was possible because I have not set the title of the x-axis.